# Ajax request runs synchronously despite not having async set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I get a "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" when running code equivalent to the following:

```
$window.bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0 && !requestProcessed) {
        requestProcessed = true;
        $.ajax(options);
    }
});
```

Where options is this:

```
var options = {
    error: function () {...},
    success: function () {...},
    type: "GET",
    url: "/home/async-contents"
};
```

My understanding is that Ajax request are `async` by default. Setting `async: true` has no effect. Why might the request still be running synchronously?

Comment: Are you sure it's synchronous? How do you determine that? Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @H.B. It just occurred to me that _this_ request isn't synchronous, but the content that is added to the body in `success` is. When I don't add to the body, I don't get the warning. Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: Sure :) Feel free to delete the question if you do not think it will be useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `success` function, I was appending the response to the body. The response had a `<script>` that was *not* asynchronous. The warning was not because the original request was running synchronously, but because the script tag from the response was being appended to the body which is a blocking operation.

Adding the `async` property to that script made it non-blocking and I stopped receiving the warning. However, it's important to note that arbitrarily marking scripts `async` can cause race conditions, and it's something that should be done on a case by case basis.